# I deleted Migrations file and folder .I try again dotnet ef migration add initial but I see Built failed

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, migration

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC app. I deleted the Migrations file and folder. I try again using .NET EF Core migration and adding initial, but I see the build failed. How can I do this?

Comment: Improve your answer please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not explain many things like did you created any other class or namespace in migrations folder and accidentally deleted it as well.

Build failed error is caused by some missing file, reference or some syntax error. 
Check you Error List tab in visual studio.

Comment: Firstly thank you .I use to write my command ">dotnet ef migrations add initial" in CLI and I could see only "Build Failed" . Then I used Package Maneger Console "PM>  add-migration initial" and take more description. when I fixed errors I am succed successful

Answer (score -1):

I use to write my command ">dotnet ef migrations add initial" in CLI and I could see only "Build Failed" . Then I used Package Maneger Console "PM> add-migration initial" and take more description. when I fixed errors I am succed successful 
[Link]https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-console-application.aspx